# One of my Application's view inside my second application in android

Tags: android, view, remoteview

I got stuck in to the problem where I need to show my first application in to some area of second application's screen. Both codes are under my control. Can any one suggest me where should I proceed as I am not getting any clue about the situation.

if some one help me for the issue, it would be a great help for me.

Or

If I can open both of my applications using the multiscreen option available in S3.

Comment: "I need to show my first application in to some area of second application's screen" -- this is not generally possible. There are ways you can have the first application send a `RemoteViews` to the second application, to have the second application display it, though this is a bit clunky and limits you to what `RemoteViews` offers.

Comment: @CommonsWare First of all, I was expecting something on this from you :)
How can I achieve that sharing of views? Will data updated with those views also be shared?

Comment: But it is not impossible too...I think!

Comment: "How can I achieve that sharing of views?" -- `RemoteViews` are `Parcelable` and therefore can be shipped using most IPC mechanisms, such as extras on `startService()` `Intents`, extras on broadcast `Intents`, or services exposing binding interfaces via AIDL.

Comment: Would the firing of any events on the buttons present in the view and any processing be work as it is as I am doing in my first application seperately?

Comment: A `RemoteViews` is limited to using a `PendingIntent` to deliver click events back to the app that defined the `RemoteViews`.

Comment: One more thing I need to know if I pass the views then I need to store them somewhere instead of layout file and then reference them? and will it cause any recompilation of project?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask, sorry.

Comment: No probs, I just wanted to know, like my situation now is: I have written an slave application which should be controlled through the master, Now there is another requirement for master app to also perform the same operation like slave. So I thought to save my efforts instead of writing the code again I could do it by displaying slave in to the master with the point master should also be visible. So what is the possibilities to achieve it?

Comment: @CommonsWare Would you mind to suggest me any example regarding the same?

Comment: "So I thought to save my efforts instead of writing the code again I could do it by displaying slave in to the master with the point master should also be visible" -- this has no chance of saving any effort. I would expect it to massively more complex. If you want to have code reuse, create an Android library project, put the reusable code there, and use that library from both apps.

Comment: But library project doesn't contains the resources...

Comment: Yes, it does. That is the complete and entire point behind an Android library project. http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects

Comment: If I move aside to library project then I would have two different project of my application, One is to make the .apk file and other is to use as the library in my master app. Am I right or can I do it with the single instance? Also Should I give the library project more preference over the remoteviews?

Comment: `MultiWindow` is a feature implemented on S3 and other Galaxy devices by `Samsung` as a system feature(by customising Android FrameWork/Platform).

Comment: @LalithB Can you suggest me how can I go with it, What changes it required to be implemented in both app codes, any blog or example?

Comment: its not possible to do it as an application, it requires modification of `Window` of the Android Platform/Framework as a whole.

Comment: Please give me a detail blog link as I will be having the access of kernels of all devices my apps will be installing on. Infact the current kernel should also be modified to install my apps which we did.

Answer (score 0):

Write a service on either of your application or a individual application. Have [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)(Android Interface Definition Language) defined as IRemoteService.aidl, the below is my pseudo code or sample implementation. Using this approach you can start activity and handle events of another application through your application.

```
// IRemoteService.aidl

// Declare any non-default types here with import statements

/** Example service interface */
interface IAccountService {
    String getLoggedInUserInfo(String appId);    
    void userLogin(String appId,ILoginCallback cb);    
    void signout(String appId);    
}
interface ILoginCallback {
    void loginSuccess(String userId);
    void loginFailed();
}
```

In your service have some RemoteCallbacks

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    final RemoteCallbackList<ILoginCallback> mCallbacks = new RemoteCallbackList<ILoginCallback>();
    if(mCallbacks!=null){
        int i = mCallbacks.beginBroadcast();
        while(i>0){
            i--;
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "Callback ...");
                mCallbacks.getBroadcastItem(i).loginSuccess(newUserId);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // The RemoteCallbackList will take care of removing                
                // the dead object for us.
            }
        }
        mCallbacks.finishBroadcast();
    }
}

private final IAccountService.Stub mBinder = new IAccountService.Stub() {
        @Override
        public void userLogin(String appId,ILoginCallback cb) throws RemoteException {
            String userId = Settings.getSettings().getUserId();
            if(userId ==null||userId.length()==0){
                mCallbacks.register(cb);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountLoginActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("deviceId", Settings.getSettings().getDeviceUniqueId());
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
}
```

You can find detailed AIDL examples in the below links.

1. http://owenhuangtw.pixnet.net/blog/post/23760257-android-aidl-(android-interface-definition-language)
2. http://www.app-solut.com/blog/2011/04/using-the-android-interface-definition-language-aidl-to-make-a-remote-procedure-call-rpc-in-android/
3. https://github.com/afollestad/aidl-example

Comment: But I wanted to show the second application on half screen while in background the current application is running!!

Comment: yeah you can get a callback when you want to show the remoteview and set the remoteview to your application, you need to handle the intent binding so the remoteview is available.

Comment: Can I show the remote view on 50% of the screen and the remaining part will be my current opened application? and will the whole application will be changed in terms of remote view if I wanted to show the full app from current opened app?

Comment: if you just wanted to show half screen of your app why not consider showing as a `Dialog` ? also if you already have sources both the apps and your logic is pre defined why not implement the remoteview as the same view and handle using a `RESTful Service`

Comment: My requirement is to show the full application inside my second app, then how would it effect the complexity if I goes with the remote view as suggested and could u provide any example of doing this?

Comment: @skygeek it is not possible to do it with your requirement until you have access to the source code, there's a possibility to do it when the target phone is rooted. refer to multi-window apps on xposed framework.